# How to get NT_Username using sql query when database is logged in under SQL Server authentication

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have logged in using SQL Server authentication, I want to retrieve the windows username using SQL query.

I tried using SYSTEM_USER and SUSER_NAME() it returns the sql logged in username and not windows NT_Username.

Is there any way to get windows NT_username ?

Thanks.

Comment: the windows name of what? the user? the server? can you be more precise please?

Comment: I strongly suspect that with SQL Server authentication your Winz user name will not be visible to SQL server. Why should it be? What if you are connecting to remote SQL server, how do you expect it (SQL server) to know remote Winz user name?